# A one day trip to Milan from Zurich

Tags: budget, trains, day-trips, milan

I am looking for a suggestion from anyone who can give me. We are boarding a group package from June 30 to July 5 for Switzerland and Paris. Last day of excursion is Zurich on 4th. 5th July is totally free and then on 6th July we have our flight to London around noon. I really want to go to Milan. Can you put forth any idea on how to go about it? Want to reach back to Zurich by 10-11 pm.

Or else any 'must see' place would do that is within a day's capacity.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  First off please review the [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) because generally recommendations and lists are considered not constructive.  If you plan to go from Zurich to Milan and Back the fastest I am able to find using public transport would be about 5 hours one way, so of the 1 day you will spend more then half of it in transit. As far as attractions please let us know your preferences to see if this is even feasible.  On top of this you might want to consider other destinations that may be better to do within a day

Answer (score 7):

It is possible. You can go by train. The trip on a direct train takes 3h40. Schedules and prices can be fond on the [SBB website](http://www.sbb.ch/). You can arrive Milan between 10:30 AM and 11:00 AM, stay until more or less 6:30 PM and be back in Zurich around 11:00 PM. The lowest price I found was 125 CHF. If possible, i.e. if your package allows this, I would already go there on the 4th in the evening.

The plane is another possibility, but nonstop flights for that particular day start at 750 EUR! And the total travel time will not be shorter when you factor in checkin and airport transfers.

On the other hand, if you live in London and you want to go to Milan, do it in a separate trip. You will find a flight ticket from London to Milan for similar prices than the price of the Zurich-Milan train ticket.

Answer (score 6):

Doing Zurich to Milan in a day is totally doable, if it's worth it it's up to you.

From [Trenitalia](http://www.trenitalia.com/cms/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=ad1ce14114bc9110VgnVCM10000080a3e90aRCRD) site you can check the train availabilty. I looked Zurigo to Milano Centrale and the first train leaves at 07:09am and arrives in Milano at 10:50am, it costs 71€. The last train leaves from Milano Centrale at 19:10 and arrives in Zurigo at 23:21, it costs the same.

With this timeframe you will be able to see the city center and the main attractions there. Let us know in detail what would you like to see.

Another possibily would be taking a [bus](http://www.oraribus.com/autobus.php?partenza=MILANO&arrivo=ZURICH) but it takes about 6 hours.